# Magento 2 dispatch observer without waiting for observer to finish

Tags: magento2, event-observer, async

I am wanting to run some code that makes a request on product save, separate to the page product save happens on.

I have correctly set up an observer that listens to the 'catalog_product_save_after' event and makes the request.

However, now when I save a product, the page waits for the observer to finish making the request before it continues and loads the 'success' page. What practice/functionality can I use such that the product save page defers the request, but doesn't need to wait on the result to continue.

Edit:

Here is the controller code that saves the product and redirects with the success message:

```
            if (isset($data['variations-matrix'])) {
            foreach ($data['variations-matrix'] as $matrixdata) {
                    $simpleids[] = $this->saveproduct($data, 'simple', $matrixdata, $blankarray = []);
                }
                    $product_id = $this->saveproduct($data, 'configurable', $blankarray = [], $simpleids);
            } else {
                $product_id = $this->saveproduct($data, $data['product_type']);
            }
            $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('The Product has been saved.'));
            return $this->_redirect('marketplace/index/products');
```

Without an observer, the success message and redirect happen almost instantly. With an observer listening to catalog_product_save_after however, the redirect and message only happen once the request is run. I am looking for a way for the request to be triggered without product save waiting for the request to finish.

Comment: When you make an after plugin you are technically still executing the save process; so it makes sense that it waits the plugin to end before making the success ? I might not have understood what you really aiming for.

Comment: @Claims, You do seem to understand, thanks for the response. My understanding of events and observers then is not great. Do you know of a way to trigger the plugin/request when the save happens, but without being tied to the save process?

Answer (score 0):

Main process execution does not wait for the observer execution when that is dispatch.

So if your plan is about wait until your code is not finished then you 2 options here.

1. Around `Plugin` (Preferred way)
2. Override the file by creating `preference`.

Comment: Hi Dhiren. So you are saying that normal behavior would be that the product save should finish even if the observer is still running? This is not the behavior I am experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understand correctly you just want to allow your code to continue running after returning control back to the caller, i.e. running  asynchronously.

There are a couple options you have here:

- There may be some optimisations you can make so that the code returns quicker,
- Create a new message-queue + consumer. Publish the task to the message queue, which will be picked up by your consumer and execute (IMHO the best option),
- Create a custom table, write required data to it, then have a cron task that reads from it and processes the rows in the table. This is essentially a roll-your-own message-queue.

Comment: I am planning on going with a message-queue and consumer. However, I have not done any work with queues before. I can't seem to find resources on queuing a message programmatically. Any help?